# FTP commands send vs put

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, ftps

I am having some issues with  a dos file we run over night that sends some files to another companies ftp server,  The other company has checked their logs and we are connecting and are able to log in but no files are ever transferred.  I was wondering if there was a difference between using the put command vs the send command.  Do newer or older systems not support one or the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linux's man page for `ftp` says that `send` is "a synonym for put".  And MS's docs for their command-line client say that "[The send command is identical to the put command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftp__send.mspx?mfr=true)".

Now, an FTP client is kinda free to do whatever it likes.  It's the FTP protocol that's standardized; the command-line interface, not so much.  (It's not even necessary that a client *have* a command-line interface; most GUI clients don't.)  But for compatibility's sake, most clients that have a command-line interface tend to agree on most of the common commands.  And the server doesn't know or care what command you typed in to send the file anyway; as long as it sees a `STOR` (the protocol-level command to send a file), assuming everything else works, the file will be transferred.

Seems like your problem is somewhere in the "everything else".